# Update child directive on click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

is there a way to update a child directive on click? In my plnkr, column 1 contains a list of names. If you click on the name it will populate the info into the contact directive in column 2. If I make a change in the textbox in column 2, the data in the info directive in column 3 will also change as well. Here is my plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/gcZbd9letYhA4ViBQJ0Q?p=preview

Here is my JS:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('contactController', function() {

  this.contacts = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Bob'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Sally'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Joe'
      }
    ]

    this.selectedContact;

    this.PublishData = function(data) {
      this.selectedContact = data;
    }

    this.UpdateData = function(data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.contacts.length; i++) {
        if (this.contacts[i].id === data.id) {
          this.contacts[i] = angular.copy(data);
        }
      }
    }
});

app.directive('contactDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'contact.html',
      scope: {
        myModel: '=',
        updateData: '&'
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

          scope.$watch('myModel', function (newValue, oldValue) {

            scope.contact = angular.copy(newValue);
          });
      }
    }
});

app.directive('infoDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'info.html',
      scope: {
        contactObject: '='
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      }
    }
});
```

Comment: your question is not so clear, can you explain it?

Comment: Yeah so infoDirective is nested inside contactDirective. When I make a change to the name for a contact, it is instantly reflected in the infoDirective. This is happening due to two-way binding because I'm passing in the same contact object to the infoDirective. What I would like is for the object to be passed into infoDirective is a one-way bind and only updates if I click save. I hope this helps and I have a link to the plnkr above as well. @FarukT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use $broadcast and $on services

with $broadcat you create an event and you pass a parameter 
with $on you listen that event and take that value

I edited your code in this way:

```
        <!--Contact template-->
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <b>Column 2</b>
          <input type="text" ng-model="newName" />
          <button ng-click="updateData({data:contact,newName:newName})">Update</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <b>Column 3</b>
          <info-directive contact-object="contact"></info-directive>
        </div>

        <!-- Your Index file -->
      <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="contactController as $ctrl">
          <div class="row col-md-12">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <b>Column 1</b>
              <div ng-repeat="contact in $ctrl.contacts">
                <a href="" ng-bind="contact.name" ng-click="$ctrl.PublishData(contact)"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <contact-directive my-model="$ctrl.selectedContact" update-data="$ctrl.UpdateData(data,newName)"></contact-directive>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>

    //and your controller
         var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('contactController', function() {

  this.contacts = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Bob'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Sally'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Joe'
      }
    ]

    this.selectedContact;

    this.PublishData = function(data) {
      this.selectedContact = data;
    }

    this.UpdateData = function(data,newName) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.contacts.length; i++) {
        if (this.contacts[i].id === data.id) {
          this.contacts[i].name = newName;
        }
      }
    }
});


app.directive('contactDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'contact.html',
      scope: {
        myModel: '=',
        updateData: '&'
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

          scope.$watch('myModel', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            scope.newName = newValue.name;
            scope.contact = angular.copy(newValue);
          });
      }
    }
});

app.directive('infoDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'info.html',
      scope: {
        contactObject: '='
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      }
    }
});
```